# Half-wave and full-wave rectifiers

Tags: circuit-design

If you add the output of a half-wave rectifier to a full wave rectifier, what can you expect as your output? Moreover, how would you actually implement this in a circuit? Do you just have the output of the half-wave rectifier connected to the input of the full-wave?

Comment: Can you explain where you got this idea and what problem you are trying to solve? A diagram would be nice and there's a nifty schematic button on the editor toolbar.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot physically connect a half wave rectifier to the output of a full wave rectifier unless you do so via an isolation transformer. A full wave rectifier comprises of two double-diode half wave rectifiers that are "added together". If you try and disrupt this by using a plain half wave rectifying diode circuit you will cause a short circuit.

Using a transformer isolation method would prevent the disruption but also give you no benefit whatsoever.

Feeding the AC through a half wave rectifier then its output through a full bridge rectifier gives you nothing except extra volt drop in the diodes.

Answer (score 0):

For the sake of academic interest, I would think that you could construct a half-wave rectifier and a full wave rectifier with two AC sources that are transformer-isolated from each other. If you connected the two un-filtered DC supplies in series, you would get a full-wave rectified source with every other half-wave having a lower amplitude. The ripple voltage would be higher than normal, but sufficiently filtered, the voltage would be near the higher peak voltage, the sum of the two AC peak voltages. Lacking suitable components to build a proper power supply, this might be a way to construct a temporary supply of a higher voltage that would be possible with either transformer by itself.